# Cursor selection behavior

Tags: macos, trackpad, mouse, text

When clicking something on the Mac screen, the cursor will

a) take up residence as directed,

If I click again, it will

b) select the whole word,

If I click again, it will

c) select the whole passage.

In Windows, I can click a fourth time, and the cursor will return to "a," the "residence" mode.  On the Mac, it stays in "whole passage" mode. I have to move the cursor out of text, so restore it to "a."

I frequently click a fourth time and expect it to return to mode A. I don't like having to correct this and move the cursor.

**How can I make the fourth click return to mode A, "residence"?**

Answer (score 2):

Clicking will reset to the "residence" mode provided that you leave enough time after the previous clicks that it isn't treated as a quadruple click.  At least, that's the way it works for me in Chrome on my MacBook Pro.

Comment: correct. Just wait a bit longer, so its not treated as a quadruple.